# Replacing an electric range with a gas range

Tags: plumbing

I want to replace an electric range with a new gas range and i am wondering about combustion air and venting requirements.

The location of the range is next to a utility room where furnace and hot water heater are located. There are two existing fresh air inlets, one near the floor, the other near the ceiling.

I am planning to tie into the existing gas line to add a short run of piping for the new gas range.

What do i need to do in order to comply with 2015 IRC?

Comment: Are you asking about installing a range hood over your new range ?

Comment: The first part of the question relates to venting: I'd like to install a 30" gas range and an over-the-range microwave that is not vented to the outside.  I"m just wondering if that sort of arrangement is acceptable. I've read other articles that suggest I should be fine with just internal recirculating venting. For gas supply, I plan to tie into existing furnace/water heater supply and i'm wondering if I could simply add a tee and run about 6' of 1/2" or 3/4" black pipe to the area near the new range, where I would then install a safety shutoff valve and short flex line to the range.

Comment: IF you have **two questions** then you need to post **two separate questions**. What are the Venting codes for a gas Range *and* How to  plumb new gas line off of an existing gas line for a new appliance. ***Edit** this one to one question and then post a new one for the other*.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - the new member site tour makes no mention of such a requirement.  But I did get an answer from someone who was apparently equipped with enough knowledge to address both questions in a single response - very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as I know, residential ranges and ovens do not require venting to the outside, only commercial locations (restaurants etc.). You might WANT to do so to get smells / cooking smoke out of the house, but it is not required. In that case, you can likely fit your over-the-stove microwave oven with a pass-through vent that would go through ducting and out the roof. DO NOT use the same venting you have for your utility room, those are different venting requirements and you do not want cooking grease venting into that room.

As to the gas pipe (although I agree, should have been a separate question), we cannot answer that from afar. Pipe size, pressure and requirements for the stove and oven are details that make a difference. Professional plumbers have calculation methods for determining that. SOMETIMES a cooperative gas utility will help you out with that because after all, they LIKE selling you more gas. If so, then yes, you can tee into an existing gas line to feed a new appliance. But be forewarned, if you have never run gas lines before and learned how to do it from someone with experience, it's not something I recommend for novices. **Mistakes can be deadly**.